# Using Ode Event in Matlab within a for Loop

Tags: matlab, for-loop, events, differential-equations

I have created an ode event as

```
options = odeset('AbsTol',1e-15,'RelTol',1e-13,'Events',@eventfunction);
[t,y,te,ye,ie]=ode45(@Equations(t,y),0:time,[b,b_e,e_infected,e_uninfected,n],options);

function [value, isterminal,direction]=eventfunction(t,y)
    value=y(1)+y(2)-1;
    isterminal=1;
    direction=0;
```

For a particular parameter set te and ye outputs are,

```
te =

   1.8555e+03


ye =

   1.0e+06 *

    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000   10.0000    0.0000
```

How do I get several ye values for one te value?
When I plot the solutions the value in which the condition is met is the first value in ye.

In here I don't understand how I get several `ye` values for one `te` value? When I plot the solutions the value in which the condition is met is the first value in `ye` and this is what I am interested in.

What I am trying to do is a sensitivity analysis and for that, I am changing the parameters at a range of values and for each parameter set I want to find the `te` and `ye` values that first meet the condition `y(1)+y(2)=1` and store these `te` and `ye` values that are obtained at each `i'th` iteration in the for loop in an array.
For this I defined as

```
a=zeros(1,1000);
b= zeros(1,1000);
```

and then within the for loop I tried to do as

```
a(i)=te
b(i)=ye
```

But then I get an error  as `index exceeds matrix dimensions`  and when I tried as `b(i)=ye(1)` I get an error as "In an assignment  A(:) = B, the number of elements in A and B must be the same."

How can I store in each iteration the first tme and the value that the event `y(1)+y(2)=1` is satisfied?
For some of these parameters it is possible that the `ye` and `te` may be empty. That is it may never be `y(1)+y(2)=1`. When that happens, I want `te` to be set to very large value as 10^5 and `ye` to be NaN.

Can someone please help me to obtain the `te` and `ye` values that first satisfies `y(1)+y(2)=1` in each loop iteration.

Comment: `ye` is simply the 5-D state vector for your five first order differential equations at the time of the event, `te`. `b` should be initialized as `zeros(1000,5);`. And the set as: `b(i,:)=ye;`.

Comment: I also recommend looking at Matlab’s `ballode` example -type `edit ballode` in your command window.

Comment: @horchler Thank you for the answer. I hadn't understood earlier that `ye` stores values  of all the states in the system at the tie the event occurs. To store values I used the method done in ballode as initializing `b=[]`  then setting as `b=[b;y(1)+y(2)]`